# How to prevent entering multiple + in a textbox in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My current code is like this

```
$('.textBoxClass').bind('keypress', function (e) {
    return (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) && e.which != 46 && e.which != 43) ? false : true;
});
```

Comment: What are you asking exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [jQuery keyup event](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/).

You need to check if `event.keyCode` is `+` and if input field already contains `+`.

If yes, you can prevent the event with `event.preventDefault()`.

Or you can use some third-part plugin like [jqueryvalidation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) and use a regular expression.

**Remember to validate the data serverside because javascript validation can be easily bypassed.**